# Autocomplete does not work for multiple fields in Solr

Tags: solr

I am able to do auto-complete for a single field but when I try to do auto-complete for multiple fields it does not work. It does not return me any result. What am I doing wrong here? Changes made in 
`Schema.xml` are as below:

```
  <field name="last_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />


<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="last_name" dest="text"/>

In Solrconfig.xml
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>      
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">text</str>
      <str name="weightField">price</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" 
                  startup="lazy" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

I am querying using the below command
http://localhost:8983/solr/search/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q="+name,

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting any errors.

Comment: what is the solr version you are using. Before solr 5.0, suggester for multivalues field was not possible.

Comment: My Solr version is 5.2.1

Comment: @AjayK I have given the answer, comment if you face any issue. Also can you add the command you are using for querying.

Comment: @abhishek I am querying the code with the above code.

Comment: @AjayK did you try the making `stored=true` in your data. You need to re-index the data.

Comment: Are you querying through code or url?

Comment: I am querying using Jquery code.I did try the stored=true and it did not work.

Comment: You need to re index the data. I hope you did that as well.

Comment: @AjayK is this resolved for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **solr 5.0** and more then only solr suggester will work for **multivalued** fields.

Your `text` field should `stored=true` then it will work. I have tested it.

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

**You need to re-index the data for storing the fields in solr.**